# how can i compare an input number and a number in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

i trying to compare a keyboard input and a already defined number in assembly but it won't work. so thats my code:

```
; is number bigger than 5 or not

  section .text
  global _start

_start:
  
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, asknum
  mov edx, lennum
  int 80h

  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, num
  mov edx, 5
  int 80h
  
  mov eax, [num]
  sub eax, '0'

  cmp eax, num5
  jg gt5 
  jl lt5
  int 80h
  jmp cont

cont:
  int 80h
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, ifequ
  mov edx, lene
  int 80h
  jmp end

gt5:
  int 80h

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, resifyes
  mov edx, lenyes
  int 80h
  jmp end

lt5:
  int 80h

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, resifno
  mov edx, lenno
  int 80h
  jmp end

end:
  mov eax, 1
  int 80h

  section .data
asknum: db "Please enter a number and i will tell you if your number bigger than 5 or not: ", 0xa, 0xd
lennum: equ $-asknum

ifequ: db "Your number is equal to five.", 0xa, 0xd
lene: equ $-ifequ

resifno: db "No, your number not bigger than 5.", 0xa, 0xd
lenno: equ $-resifno

resifyes: db "Yes, your number bigger than 5", 0xa, 0xd
lenyes: equ $-resifyes

num5: db 5

  segment .bss
num resb 5
```

but i receive same line 'no, your number not bigger than 5.'
i compile with nasm and ld so maybe i miss some flags but i couldn't find that.

i tried everything about data types and i still can not solve it. by the way i trying to execute on linux if you need.

Comment: What kind of input number are you expecting to use?  If a single digit, you should read 1 byte, not 5, and load the result into an 8-bit register as 1201ProgramAlarm states.  If multi-digit, you have to write a proper decimal to binary conversion routine; subtracting `'0'` only works for single digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a 32 bit register (`eax`) when you should be using an 8 bit one (`al`) when loading from `num` and comparing with `num5`. Correcting the syntax so you compare with the value of `num5` instead of the address, you get:

```
mov al,[num]
sub al,'0'

cmp al,[num5]
```

Comment: `resb 5` looks like NASM, and these are Linux system calls, so we can be pretty sure this *is* NASM/YASM, and `[]` are needed for memory references.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the confirmation. I've rephrased the answer slightly.